# Can we have an eigenfunction that belongs to $L^{2}$ ($L=$ angular momentum operator) but not to $ L_{x}, L_{y}, or L_{z} $?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum

As the eigenspace of $L^{2}$ is much bigger than the eigenspace of $ L_{x}, L_{y}, or L_{z} $. In the Venn diagram of $L^{2}$ and $ L_{x}, L_{y}, or L_{z} $, the $L^{2}$ Eigenspace constitutes all the cartesian Angular momentum components.

[image: Image screen from the Richard L. Liboff Book on Quantum Mechanics]

Comment: What do you mean "belongs to"?

Comment: Please rewrite your question to make it clear what you are asking. For example, your first sentence can not be parsed as a complete sentence (since it begins with "As" it is just a fragment).

Answer (score 4):

> Can we have an eigenfunction that belongs to $L^{2}$ (L= angular momentum operator) but not to $ L_{x}, L_{y}, or L_{z} $?

Not sure what "belongs to... " means here, but if it means "is an eigenfunction of..." then yes. This is what the picture you posted shows (i.e., that there are more eigenfunctions of $L^2$ then there are of all the $L_i$ together).

Again, not sure exactly what the *question* is, since the diagram you posted already seems to answer the question you asked in the title... If you are just looking for an example you can consider, for example:
$$
f(\theta,\phi) = \alpha Y_{1,0} + \beta Y_{1,1} + \gamma Y_{1,-1}\;,
$$
which is generally an eigenfunction of $L^2$ (for *any* alpha, beta, and gamma), but is not an eigenfunction of any of the individual $L_i$ in general.

Comment: yeah. I was actually looking for an example. Thanks for providing!

Comment: you could presumably get unlucky and have your coefficients so the state is an eigenstate of one of the three but for generic coefficients this will not be the case…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It seems to me that I stated this caveat in the answer already: "...generally an eigenfunction of $L^2$." Maybe not clear enough, though... Is it not clear that my "generally" means effectively the same thing as your "generic"? Clearly a specific case like $\beta=\gamma=0$ can be an eigenfunction of both $L^2$ and $L_z$. Anyways, I guess it is not worth updating the answer since the comments address it.

Comment: it is NOT worth updating.

Comment: for spin 1/2, any combination of the two states is an eigenstate along some axis, but that doesn't hold for $L=1$, which is why chemist can talk about $P_x$, $P_y$, and $P_z$ orbitals, and nuclear physicists can measure $t_{20}$, the tensor polarization of the deuteron.